# Is there any way to keep a link unmodified when crawled by Archive-It?

Tags: internet-archive

We are using Archive-It's "Standard" seed type (see https://support.archive-it.org/hc/en-us/articles/208332843-Assign-and-edit-a-seed-type-), and wish to keep some links, particularly to external websites unmodified by Archive-It so that they go directly to the external site rather than "dead ending" in Archive-It.  Is there some attribute that can be added to links to leave them untouched?

Here is an example Archive-It archived page: https://wayback.archive-it.org/6087/20151201201134/http://2014.placonference.org/ -- how would one designate the Facebook link so that it does not go to ArchiveIt?  It does not have to actually go to Facebook -- the archive of Facebook on https://archive.org/web/ would be fine.

Comment: Can you share an example of an archived page that could benefit from this?   I've never used this archive before.   I spent a little time trying to find some examples, but I couldn't figure out how to actually view archived content from their home page.

Comment: Added an example to the original post.